# CURL request only works outside of VM

Tags: 18.04, curl

VM: Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu 18.04.

Curl version: 7.58.0

Command used: curl -v "http://IP:PORT/PATH"

Result:

```
* Trying IP...
* Connected to IP (IP) port PORT(#0)
> GET /PATH HTTP/1.1
> Host: IP:PORT
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

And it just stays stuck there. What's weirder is that if I have an invalid query string parameter in the path, I get response from the server with custom json body. If I do the same request outside the VM with postman, I get the response. The server is owned by us so if I see the logs on the server, I see that it handled the request (I cannot debug it though).

What's up here? Is the length of the request breaking curl? Otherwise I'll just assume part of the code is cutting us off at the very end if my IP is bad. Does a request from the VM have different IP than outside of it?